# How to Append a file and concatenate text in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to put a new line next to each URL that I save in a file. Therefore, I used the following code in php:

```
file_put_contents("test.txt", $url."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

But when I open the file, all the URLs I put in the file is in one line and the new line hasn't been inserted.

Comment: Same code i am using and it is working fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\r\n` because `\n` used to new line and `\r` used for end of the current line.

> Unix tends to use `\n` as a line separator; Windows tends to use `\r\n` as a line separator and Macs (up to OS 9) used to use `\r` as the line separator.

Answer (score 1):

They are in different lines, but you are using the UNIX newline format, therefore some Windows programs like Notepad will not understand this right.

Use `\r\n` instead of just `\n`, or get a better text editor.